# When using an API route, return Http Response 401 instead of redirect to login page when not authorised

Tags: httpresponse, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, http-status-code-401

I'm building an ASP.NET Core 2.0 website using MVC and WebAPI to provide access to a series of microservices. Where a WebAPI controller requires a user to be authenticated and authorised (using the `Authorize` attribute), any unauthorised or not-logged in user gets the response back as the entire HTML for the MVC login page.

**When unauthorised users access the API, I would like to return the HTTP status code 401 and its associated error message in the response, instead of an entire HTML page.**

I've looked at a few existing questions and noticed that they either refer to ASP.NET MVC (such as [SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication in WebApi.Owin also suppressing authentication outside webapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878446/suppressdefaulthostauthentication-in-webapi-owin-also-suppressing-authentication)) which is no good for ASP.NET Core 2.0. Or they are using a hackaround for Core 1.x, which just doesn't seem right ([ASP.Net core MVC6 Redirect to Login when not authorised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41442234/asp-net-core-mvc6-redirect-to-login-when-not-authorised)).

Has a proper solution been implemented in Core 2.0 that anyone is aware of? If not, any ideas how it could be implemented properly?

For reference, there's part of a controller as an example:

```cs
[Authorize]
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/V{ver:apiVersion}/Organisation")]
public class OrganisationController : Controller
{
    ...

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        return await _organisationService.GetAllSubdomains();
    }

    ...
}
```

And the configurations within *Statup.cs*:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    // Add API version control
    services.AddApiVersioning(options =>
    {
        options.ReportApiVersions = true;
        options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
        options.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
        options.ErrorResponses = new DefaultErrorResponseProvider();
    });

    // Add and configure MVC services.
    services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(setupAction =>
        {
            // Configure the contract resolver that is used when serializing .NET objects to JSON and vice versa.
            setupAction.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
         });

    ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    ...

    app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/error/index?errorCode={0}");

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
       {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

       });

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is an easy way to suppress redirect to Login page for unathorized requests. Just add following call of `ConfigureApplicationCookie` extension method in your `ConfigureServices`:

```cs
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
});
```

Or if you need custom error message in response body:

```cs
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = async context =>
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Some custom error message if required");
    };
});
```

As far as you're using redirects to custom error pages for error codes (`UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects()` call in `Configure` method), you should add filter for 401 error. To achieve this, remove call to `UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects` and use `UseStatusCodePages` extension method with skip of redirect for Unauthorized code:

```cs
//app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/error/index?errorCode={0}");
app.UseStatusCodePages(context =>
{
    if (context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode != (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
    {
        var location = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "/error/index?errorCode={0}", context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode);
        context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(location);
    }
    return Task.CompletedTask;
});
```

Comment: That's absolutely spot on, and thank you for the extra `UseStatusCodePages()` settings, that would have otherwise caused another couple of hours of grief to figure out too!

Comment: Is it possible to do it only for WebApi calls and not page requests?

Comment: Sure. In passed lambda you have access to `HttpContext`. You could easily add condition based on request uri.

Comment: In case of the url where you don't want to suppress, what do you need to return in order to proceed with redirecting to login page?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JWT for authentication with an ASP.NET Core 2 API; you can configure the unauthorized response when you're configuring the services for Authentication & JWT:

```
        services.AddAuthentication( JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme )
                .AddJwtBearer(options => options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
                {
                    OnAuthenticationFailed = c =>
                    {
                        c.NoResult();

                        c.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                        c.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

                        return c.Response.WriteAsync("There was an issue authorizing you.");
                    }
                });
```