# How to redirect ASP.Net 5 (Core) Authorize attribute to 401

Tags: asp.net, authentication, redirect, openid-connect

### Question

Hi. I'm working on an ASP.Net 5 (Core not MVC5) web API. I'm using a cookie authentication scheme with an external OpenID Connect identity provider. I'm using an `Authorize` attribute to secure an action to authenticated users only. Since this is a web API, I want the server to return 401 to the client when trying to access such an action endpoint without being authenticated. However, I'm always being redirected to the login page of my OpenID Connect provider.

### Setup

---

Here's the relevant services configuration:

`Startup.cs`

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddControllersWithViews(...);

  services
  .AddAuthentication(options =>
  {
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignOutScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
  })
  .AddCookie(...)
  .AddOpenIdConnect(...)
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
  app.UseRouting();
  app.UseAuthentication();
  app.UseAuthorization();
  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute());
}
```

My endpoint essentially looks like the following:

`FooController.cs`

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class FooController : ControllerBase
{
  [Authorize]
  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult<int> GetBar()
  {
    return Ok(1);
  }
}
```

### Attempts

---

I've attempted to do as solutions on other questions have suggested such as this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47987035/11800986. I set these redirect events when adding the cookie authentication.

`Startup.cs`

```cs
.AddCookie(options =>
{
  options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
  {
    context.Response.Clear();
    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
    return Task.CompletedTask;
  };
  options.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = context =>
  {
    context.Response.Clear();
    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
  };
})
```

When I run the server in debugging mode and set breakpoints inside these redirect handlers, they never even fire. This should be because I am using OpenId Connect as the default challenge scheme, not cookies.

To try to solve this, I've attached to an OpenId Connect event in a similar fashion:

`Startup.cs`

```cs
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
  options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
  {
    context.Response.Clear();
    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
    return Task.CompletedTask;
  };
});
```

This event does get hit when I debugged it with a breakpoint but it doesn't seem to stop the redirection at all.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Pure API's should not use AddCookie or AddOpenIDConnect, instead they should only be using the AddJwtBearer authentication handler, to receive access tokens and convert them to ClaimsPrincipal user objects.

Or is this a combined API and client application?

Comment: If it is combined, what is the solution? I have a combined application