# .Net 5 MVC Modal Login on unauthorized event

Tags: c#

I am trying to make use of login modal popup in mvc when a user clicks on a route that requires authentication instead of routing to normal view.  Something like the answer in this question [ASP.NET MVC Authorize Attribute to launch a modal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174713/asp-net-mvc-authorize-attribute-to-launch-a-modal)

What should I use within the .Net 5 framework to get the same functionality?

I have tried using the IAuthorizationFilter but this is not called with the Authorized attribute and everything I try to search on the subject keeps leading me back to the full framework implementations

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class ModalLoginAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
```

EDIT:
@Christoph Lütjen Was thinking of making the login look like a modal but want to keep all the bootstrap animation without doing to much work.
I implemented the solution by making a new view to redirect to that will then execute the script in the view.
If someone do know how to do it with attribute as the above linked question please let me know.

The extra login action in the authentication controller

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult LoginReroute(string ReturnUrl)
{
      ViewData["OpenAuthorizationPopup"] = GetLoggedInUser()?.Authenticated != true;
      ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = ReturnUrl;
      return View();
}
//Then in the view for this new view 
@if ((bool)(ViewData["OpenAuthorizationPopup"] ?? true))
{
    var returnurl = ViewData["ReturnUrl"];
    <script>showModalLogin('@returnurl')</script>
}
//And finally set startup class to use the redirect login action on unauth event
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(options =>
                {
                    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(2);
                    options.LoginPath = "/Auth/LoginReroute";
                });
```

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't designed to give "guides" on complex topics. Can you [edit] your post to include a [mre] of what you have tried so far, and explain the issue you're having?

Comment: Btw. You are aware of the the problem that all this happens AFTER the navigation, so you could simply style your login page and make it look like a popup.

Comment: My first though on this is to extend the [Authorize] attribute (see here some example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41442234/asp-net-core-mvc6-redirect-to-login-when-not-authorised ) so you can treat whatever happens when the user is not authorized. Decorate the controller action with [ModalLoginAuthorize]

Comment: @DorinBaba thanks will look at the attribute question you link early next week.  appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I need to handover project to other devs in future I went with the simple implementation that works.

The solution in the edit of my question.  Just making the answer if someone else looking for how to do it.

In your startup configurations set your reroute url to a new login method in your auth controller.

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(options =>
                {
                    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(2);
                    options.LoginPath = "/Auth/LoginReroute";
                });
```

Then in your new action in the controller add the following

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult LoginReroute(string ReturnUrl)
{
      ViewData["OpenAuthorizationPopup"] = true; //Can do checks to see if user is logged in first here
      ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = ReturnUrl; //Used so that we can send on the return url after login is done
      return View(); //You can return any other view on your site for example "~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml"
}
```

In the view that you return add the following at the top.

```
@if ((bool)(ViewData["OpenAuthorizationPopup"] ?? true))
{
    var returnurl = ViewData["ReturnUrl"];
    <script>showModalLogin('@returnurl')</script>
}
```

In your javascript where you have your bootstrap modal js stuff add the method for the showModalLogin function.

```
function bindForm(dialog) {

    $('form', dialog).submit(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.success) {
                    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                    if (result.redirect === undefined)
                        location.reload();
                    else
                        location.href = result.redirect;
                } else {
                    $('#myModalContent').html(result);
                    bindForm();
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
}

function showModalLogin(returnurl) {
    $('#myModalContent').load("/Auth/Login?ReturnUrl=" + returnurl, function () {

        $('#myModal').modal({
            keyboard: true
        }, 'show');

        bindForm(this);
    });

    return false;
}
```