# Automatic Redirect on Authorize Failure Using IIS Automatic Authentication with ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, iis, active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc, authorization

I am creating a website in ASP.Net Core MVC and using IIS's automatic authentication to have users of the company automatically be validated through active directory. This is working as it should at the moment, however, **I'd like to redirect users to a log in page if they can not be validated through IIS.** I've seen other posts describing how to do this when using a normal authentication cookie, but not with this automatic authentication.

This is my current Configure Services method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.AutomaticAuthentication = true;
    });

    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}
```

So at the moment it is successfully locking out users who do not have AD authorization on a page marked [Authorize], I'd just like to redirect that locked out traffic to another page marked [AllowAnonymous]. Is there a way to modify the services.Configure method? So far I do not see anything.

Comment: see if the answers for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40217623/9534819) works for you

Comment: When IIS failed to authenticate a Windows user, it sends back a 401.1 error page. So you can configure a custom error page there to perform redirection.

Comment: @Matt.G I've seen many solutions regarding using cookies; I guess that would be part of my question: can I use this IIS authentication as a cookie?

Answer (score 1):

What you're using is called [Windows Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth). The reference to [`AutomaticAuthentication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/index?view=aspnetcore-2.2#iis-options) just tells IIS to automatically set `HttpContext.User` with the user details (otherwise it doesn't, even if the authentication succeeded).

What you're looking for is really two authentication methods: For people with AD accounts (who are logged in with those accounts), log them in automatically using Windows Authentication. Otherwise, show a login screen and you can handle the authentication yourself.

I've done this before in ASP.NET MVC, but I haven't (yet) done it in ASP.NET Core. I'll describe what I did, but this isn't a complete solution since there's a missing piece for ASP.NET Core.

[Use cookies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie) for your main authentication method. Set it up like normal, with a login page where you validate the credentials and [set the cookie](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-2.2#create-an-authentication-cookie).

Setup one controller action (lets say, `/Login/SSO`) that uses Windows Authentication. I did that using a `location` tag in the web.config. That is still likely the same in ASP.NET Core, I'm just not entirely sure how you pick up on that in the code. But the part in web.config would look something like this:

```
<location path="Login/SSO">
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <authentication>
          <windowsAuthentication enabled="true"/>
          <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false"/>
        </authentication>
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

In the code for that action, assuming you can figure out how to grab the username from the Windows Authentication, you set the cookie and return a 200 OK (you don't need to return a view). If Windows Authentication fails, IIS will return a 401 on its own. (I think the `<allow users="?"/>` was just to prevent the cookie authentication from trying to redirect - but I can't remember)

The fancy trick is on the login page. Hide everything on the page by default. On page load, do an AJAX request to `/Login/SSO`. If it succeeds, then the user is logged in and you can forward them (via javascript) to the page they want. If it fails, just show the contents of the login page. That would look something like this (assuming you're using jQuery):

```
$(function() {
    $.get("@Url.Action("SSO", "Login")").done(function(data) {
        //success! forward to the page they want
        window.location.replace(returnUrl);
    }).fail(function() {
        //failed - show login prompt
        $("#loginBox").show();
    });
});
```

With this setup, a user who can be authenticated using Windows authentication will hit the site, get redirected to the login page, the login page does a successful AJAX request that creates their cookie, and they get redirected back to the original page they wanted. Pretty seamless.