# How to redirect user to Login page instead of 401 error with BasicAuthentication (c# dotnet core)?

Tags: c#, .net-core, basic-authentication

Alright so I'm using netcoreapp2.2 , and I have configured my project to use "BasicAuthentication" and everything seems alright with that.

```
            services.AddAuthentication("BasicAuthentication")
                .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, BasicAuthenticationHandler>("BasicAuthentication",null);
```

But what is happening is, wherever theres the [Authorize], makes the page return a 401 error (which I've seen is normal for the BasicAuthentication),but  how do I make it redirect instead to my Login view? instead of the 401 ?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40217623/redirect-to-login-when-unauthorized-in-asp-net-core

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ConfigureApplicationCookie extension on services to specify the login page path. When you get a 401 it will be automatically redirected to there.

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => options.LoginPath = "pathToLoginPage");
```