# How to force start Asp.Net Core 3.0 application to use Identity Login Page

Tags: c#, startup, asp.net-core-3.0

I use Asp.Net Core 3.0.1 and I need to force redirect to Identity Login Page, but, the problem after I changed the startup configuration it still redirect me to /Home/Index page, and here is my startup class code:

```
public class Startup
{
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //Conection Provider for Identity
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("yourConnection")));

    services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();


    services.AddMemoryCache();


    services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
    {
        //Password Settings
        options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
        options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
        options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
        options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;

        //Lockout Settings
        options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 3;
        options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

        //User settings
        options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+#";
        options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;

    });

    //Configure application cookie
    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        options.LoginPath = "/Login";
        options.LogoutPath = "/Logout";
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/AccessDenied";
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    });


    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
    })
    .SetCompatibilityVersion(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0)
    .AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();


    services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
    services.AddSession(options => {
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
    });


    services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>(i =>
        new EmailSender(
            Configuration["EmailSender:Host"],
            Configuration.GetValue<int>("EmailSender:Port"),
            Configuration.GetValue<bool>("EmailSender:EnableSSL"),
            Configuration["EmailSender:UserName"],
            Configuration["EmailSender:Password"]
        ));

    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddRazorPages(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.ConfigureFilter(new IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
    });

}


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();


    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseSession();
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        //routes.MapRoute(
        //    name: "Identity",
        //    template: "Identity/{controller=Account}/{action=Login}/{id?}");

        routes.MapAreaRoute(
            name: "Identity",
            areaName: "Identity",
            template: "Identity/{controller=Account}/{action=Login}/{id?}");


    });

    app.UseCookiePolicy();

    CreateRoles(serviceProvider).Wait();
    RotativaConfiguration.Setup((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment) env);

}
```

> **How can I force my application to startup with /Account/Login in Identity area?**

Here is some link I searched in the same problem:

1. [Redirect to login when unauthorized in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40217623/redirect-to-login-when-unauthorized-in-asp-net-core)
2. https://wakeupandcode.com/authentication-authorization-in-asp-net-core-razor-pages/
3. https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/09/16/cookie-authentication-asp-net-core-2-0/

Comment: Your code is one mix of legacy and endpoint routing. Good chance that code is ignored because of that. Try to remove the old code (AddMvc, EnableEndpointRouting = false, UseMvc) and migrate to EndpointRouting (UseEndpoints). You already have AddControllersWithViews, combined with AddRazorPages (no need for AddMvc). Check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#migrate-startupconfigure).

Comment: In general, defining template routes do not force the user to the login page. The only thing that does, is when the user hits a secured page. So in order to redirect an anonymous user to the login page, is to add a global filter that requires that. For AddControllersWithViews: `options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build()))`, and for RazorPages probably some convention. This will only work for anonymous users, which is I assume the purpose.

Comment: For an exact order check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.0#order).

Answer (score 2):

I use netcore 3.0 too.

My differences between on you code

```
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

Mycode is working on when cookie is not valid. I use cookie like this

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(options =>
                {
                    options.Cookie.Name = "<Your cookiename>";
                    options.LoginPath = "auth/login";//This should login page path
                    options.LogoutPath = "auth/logout";//This should logout page path
                    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
                    options.SlidingExpiration = false;
                });
```

I Hope it's help :)

Comment: I tried to apply but, I phased one problem, this code gives me error `configuration.Cookie.CoookieName; 
configuration.Cookie.LoginPath;
`

Comment: Ohh no, configuration.Cookie just **my code peace** ali, sorry about that. You have to edit your configuration. Ex: **options.LoginPath = "auth/login"** **options.LogoutPath="auth/logout"** I am editing my answer to more clear

Comment: In migration guide we don't use UseMvc anymore, we use UseEndpoints instead, you can look in https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#routing-startup-code

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but, until now The problem still there.

Answer (score 1):

I have similar issue, after wasting hours, I solved this by putting [Authorized] attribute on top of the class. I hope I've helped someone on this. :)

```
[Authorize]
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

    public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had that problem before, in the .net core 2.2 and I fixed it in the **launchSettings.json** file as you can see in [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

It seems to work for version 3 as well, as you can see in the example below for multiple environments:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:54339/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_My_Environment": "1",
        "ASPNETCORE_DETAILEDERRORS": "1",
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Staging"
      }
    },
    "EnvironmentsSample": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Staging"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:54340/"
    },
    "Kestrel Staging": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_My_Environment": "1",
        "ASPNETCORE_DETAILEDERRORS": "1",
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Staging"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:51997/"
    }
  }
}
```

In my case I had to add `"launchUrl": "my url"`

Like the following snippet:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false, 
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "launchUrl": "[your url here]"
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "[your url here]",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```